# CouchBase - JavaContext not found in Android Studio

Tags: android, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I am following the [instruction](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.2/installation/android/index.html) to set up CouchBase in Android Studio.

The problem is that `JavaContext` does not seem to exist. Any idea why ?

```
private void test(){
    // Enable logging
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger("app");
    log.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    JavaContext context = new JavaContext(); // THIS LINE DOES NOT COMPILE
    // Create a manager
            Manager manager = null;
            try {
                manager = new Manager(context, Manager.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    // Create or open the database named app
            Database database = null;
            try {
                database = manager.getDatabase("app");
            } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    // The properties that will be saved on the document
            Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            properties.put("title", "Couchbase Mobile");
            properties.put("sdk", "Java");
    // Create a new document
            Document document = database.createDocument();
    // Save the document to the database
            try {
                document.putProperties(properties);
            } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    // Log the document ID (generated by the database)
    // and properties
    log.info(String.format("Document ID :: %s", document.getId()));
    log.info(String.format("Learning %s with %s", (String) document.getProperty("title"), (String) document.getProperty("sdk")));
}
```

Here is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.woxthebox.draglistview.sample"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    // workaround for "duplicate files during packaging of APK" issue
// see https://groups.google.com/d/msg/adt-dev/bl5Rc4Szpzg/wC8cylTWuIEJ
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':library')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:1.3.0'
}
```

EDIT:

After some playing around I found that this code works:

```
    private void test(){
        // Enable logging
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger("app");
        log.setLevel(Level.ALL);
       // JavaContext context = new JavaContext();

        // Create a manager
                Manager manager = null;
                try {
                    manager = new Manager(new AndroidContext(getApplicationContext()), Manager.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        // Create or open the database named app
                Database database = null;
                try {
                    database = manager.getDatabase("app");
                } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        // The properties that will be saved on the document
                Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                properties.put("title", "Couchbase Mobile");
                properties.put("sdk", "Java");
        // Create a new document
                Document document = database.createDocument();
        // Save the document to the database
                try {
                    document.putProperties(properties);
                } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        // Log the document ID (generated by the database)
        // and properties
        log.info(String.format("Document ID :: %s", document.getId()));
        log.info(String.format("Learning %s with %s", (String) document.getProperty("title"), (String) document.getProperty("sdk")));
    }
```

Can someone explain what was wrong with the original instructions ?

Comment: I have poor experiences with Couchbase documentation. It looks like according to the Github project `JavaContext` doesn't even exist in the master branch. So, try going from here. http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.2/develop/training/build-first-android-app/starter-code-android/index.html

Comment: Apologies for this, it was updated today in https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-mobile-portal/commit/84713c4ed1659c365f06b9c7df41cb2b0778f50e and should be published now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone explain what was wrong with the original instructions ?

Probably whoever wrote the documentation didn't know there was a [`AndroidContext`](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android/blob/master/src/main/java/com/couchbase/lite/android/AndroidContext.java) for the Android Couchbase Lite.

Whereas, for a standard Java (embedded?) project, there actually is a [`JavaContext`](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/couchbase/lite/JavaContext.java).

The Getting Started code on Github does actually use an `AndroidContext` too, so that page is just wrong.

See here for the (seemingly correct) [Couchbase Android - Getting Started Guide](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.2/develop/training/build-first-android-app/index.html)